# 301 redirect based on text to new url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having a little problem with an URL. I hope you can help me out!

I have this url:

```
http://www.domain.com/search.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_softy.tpl&product_id=1408&category_id=1028
```

This needs to be redirected to:

```
http://www.domain.com/search.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_color_plus.tpl&product_id=1408&category_id=1028
```

The only thing that needs to be changed is the flypage=vmj_softy to flypage=vmj_color_plus

The product ID and Category ID has to be a string (at has to change on all products)

I Think I need to use apaches mod_rewrite for this, but i've tried everything but I'm not able to get this to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_softy.tpl(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?search.html$ /search.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_color_plus.tpl%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @user1678766 Can you be any more descriptive besides "it does not work"?

Comment: It does not redirect to the correct page.

Check it on: http://www.all4honda.com/zoeken.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_softy.tpl&product_id=1408&category_id=1028

Comment: @WNRDesign I don't understand, that looks nothing like what you are asking in your question.